# Wampserver: Error after upgrading to php5.5 - Entry Point Not found

Tags: php, wampserver

I have this error - Entry Point Not Found - after upgrading my wampserver's php to 5.5.8

Did anyone know what it mean? What I have mis-configured and how I can to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post in the WAMPServer forum. There was a little bug in the WAMPServer 2.4 release that effects the code that does the version switching [see here for the fix](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,120417,120417#msg-120417)

This may be the reason for your problem.

Also check your httpd.conf file here

```
LoadModule php5_module "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.8/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

Make sure it is loading the right php interpreter into apache. If this is wrong then it is almost definitely caused by the above bug and should be corrected by the fix.

Comment: Yea it is changed to LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.8/php5apache2_4.dll" in my wampsever....

Comment: Using the `wampmanager` icon ( The green W in the system tray ) there are menus. Left click `wampmanager` then follow the menus `wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf`